# Where are the mythtv-setup backend start/stop scripts in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, scripts, systemd, mythtv

According to https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Setup_General#Backend_Control, ubuntu supplies scripts to start and stop the backend, ignoring the setting in mythtv-setup.  Where are those scripts?  On my 15.04 system, they are still attempting to use upstart to do this, which of course doesn't work as 15.04 uses systemd.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the web page is wrong.  What was throwing me off was that you can't use sudo (as suggested on the mythtv-setup page), that hangs the shutdown (I assume it's asking for the password on the terminal), you need to use kdesudo.